# Uses for a sushi mat other than making sushi

Tags: equipment, sushi

I recently tried sushi for the first time by making it myself. While I loved the rice and insides, I sadly did not like the flavor of the seaweed. I don’t think I will make sushi for myself in the future. (I will, however, be making lots of other ‘sushi’ like recipes!)

Because of this, I now have a sushi mat that I don’t have much use for. So is there anything I can do with my mat (cooking or otherwise) other than make sushi?

Comment: Use it for sushi rolls that don’t have nori on the outside?

Comment: As Stephie mentioned, you should look up "inside out" sushi rolls, also known as uramaki.  It was developed for American palettes, where they weren't used to the flavor and texture of nori.

Comment: And if you're really giving up, most rolling mats can also be used as a trivot

Answer (score 2):

Jelly roll, spring roll, joconde, meat roll, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use them as place mat or table mat, depending on the size.

Or as mentioned in the comments, sushi like rolls of rice with little or no seaweed.
There are 'sushi' kind of rolls, uramaki according to the comment by @Joe, where the nori is on the inside, just outside the fish and/or vegetables, but you can make rolls which have no nori at all.

Sushi is blobs of rice with fish, omlette or even vegetables on top, with a strip of nori to keep them together. You can make those without the nori as well, especially if you do not need to transport them.

For those who do not like (or for other reasons eat) fish, there are fish free versions. Vegetarian or vegan, or with meat replacing fish.